# Scrolling body text on Android Notification

Tags: android, notifications

Is there a way to get the body text of a notification to scroll along the notification?

[image: Highlighted text area]

If this text is too long it just fades out at the border near the time. Is there a way to make it scroll slowly along so that someone could read it while in the notification drop down menu without having to either read it when it ticks along the status bar when it is received, but without going into the app?

I think this would be possible with a custom notification layout that housed XML with scrolling views, but i cannot use a custom layout, the notifications need to be created through the default notification creator.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Edit: im in no way affiliated with Onavo Lite, it was just a image i found to point out the text area i want to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the default notification layout uses TextViews with a maximum size and no scrolling features.